# "Garage sale" chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm cleaning up my office and came across a few recent issues of a programming magazine I've never actually managed to read and that I'm happy to give away.

Those magazines in question are probably better given away through german-speaking PHP channels as they are german and PHP related, but it made me think of a general idea. What about opening a chat room for giving away old programming books, magazines, or even old software licenses?

On an entirely non-commercial, recipient-pays-shipping-in-advance basis?

It could maybe even serve as a bulletin board for other kinds of things I've seen requested here on Meta, like for looking for people to start Open Source projects with.

Would this be worth a shot?

Or are there better channels for this and this is a stupid idea?

Just thinking. I wouldn't just want to open a chat room - it would be certain to wither away. But if there's some positive feedback, and some people who actually have something to give away or put in there, it would be worth trying out. It would also (in my opinion) need some rules what can go in there, and what can't.

Comment: We could name it `craigslist.chat.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I am not in the market for those kinds of services performed by SO users. Thanks for offering, though.

Comment: It could be `exchange.stackexchange.com`

Comment: great idea .... so many of us have books gathering dust